# How to download the content of an ubuntu archive with wget via Windows

Tags: windows, networking, deployment, wget

I want to download an ubuntu archive of the ubuntu focal distribution to put it on one of our ftp servers (windows server 2016) and install our systems with a kickstarter file which looks like this.

```
..
d-i mirror/protocol string ftp
d-i mirror/ftp/hostname string 172.16.0.4
d-i mirror/ftp/directory string /Ubuntu-20.04/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
d-i mirror/ftp/proxy string
..
```

I want to do it on windows because we have both linux installs and windows installs to deploy via this server, and I find the file management much more handy on windows. I know there are plenty of tutorials and procedures with ubuntu servers with grub bootloaders but in this case it's a bit different, we have a windows server with syslinux.

I red the thread here how to mirror an archive with wget on ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701842/how-do-you-mirror-an-archive-with-wget)..
I need to clone the following mirrors

```
--> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal
--> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security
--> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates
--> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/
```

How can I do it in cmd? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

1 - I download Wget for windows via [sourceforge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

2 - I put the wget.exe file in c:\Windows\System32 folder to call it via cmd with > wget
3 - I type in the following commands after making a c:\ubuntu2004 folder:

```
> cd c:\Ubuntu2004
> wget --continue --recursive --no-parent -R "index.html*" -r http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal
> wget --continue --recursive --no-parent -R "index.html*" -r http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/
> wget --continue --recursive --no-parent -R "index.html*" -r http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/
> wget --continue --recursive --no-parent -R "index.html*" -r http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/
```

Now there I need a lot of space especially for the pool folder. But its no problem if you have a 500GB disk.